# How to filter results in a Spring repository by a value when searching from a "parent entity"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot and I have those entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
@NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findAll", query="select u from Usuario u where 
u.estactiv=true order by u.user")
public class Usuario implements Serializable{
...
@Column(name="usu_estactiv",nullable=false)
private boolean estactiv=true;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Roles> roles = new ArrayList<>();
...}



@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@NamedQuery(name = "Roles.findAll", query="select r from Roles r where 
r.estactiv=true order by r.descripcion")
public class Roles implements Serializable{
...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  
@JoinColumn(columnDefinition="integer", name="usu_id", nullable=false)
@JsonBackReference
private Usuario user;

@Column(name="rol_estactiv",nullable=false)
private boolean estactiv=true;
...}
```

And in my repositories:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "usuario", path = "usuario")
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Usuario, 
Integer> {

@Override
@Query
public Page<Usuario> findAll(Pageable pageable);

Usuario findByUserAndEstactivTrue(@Param("user") String user);
}



@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "roles", path = "roles")
public interface RolesRepository extends 
PagingAndSortingRepository<Roles,Integer>{

@Override
@Query
public Page<Roles> findAll(Pageable pageable);

@Override
@Query
public Iterable<Roles> findAll();
}
```

When I go to the url:
http://localhost:8080/api/usuario/  I get the users with estactiv=true:

[image]

but when I go to http://localhost:8080/api/usuario/1/roles, I got this:

[image]

And I just want **to get the roles with estactiv=true for each user** ,for example:

The user admin (with id=1) has two roles: user(false) and admin(true) in my roles table, but when I go to /api/usuario/1/roles I just want to get admin (true)

I hope my question is clear, if not please let me know in order to fix it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a join with the table `usario` in your roles query in order to filter on the `estactiv` property of the `usario` table. The query should look like this:

```
select r
from Roles r
inner join Usario u on r.usu_id=u.id
where u.estactiv=true
order by r.descripcion
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, I got an error when I add the inner join in the @NamedQuery (org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: Roles.findAll), and I want just the roles with estactiv true,for example, for the user admin (wit id 1) when I go to /api/usuario/1/roles I just want the roles with estactiv true

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter the list further, make use of `Query string` and pass parameter as the query string in your URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/usuario/1/roles?estactiv=true.
```

Now, you can able to filter the output result on the basis of this query string try to filter your data probably by writing a new query/code behind.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading the documentation and I find a solution:

First in my RolesRepository, I declare this method:

```
public Collection<Roles> findByEstactivTrueAndUserId(@Param("user") Integer 
user);
```

Then in my UserController:

```
 @GetMapping("/api/usuario/{userId}/roles")
    public Collection<Roles> getRoles(@PathVariable Integer userId) {
        return rolRepo.findByEstactivTrueAndUserId(userId);
 }
```

And when I go to http://localhost:8080/api/usuario/1/roles , I get only the roles with estactiv=true for usuario with id=1.